# Receive input from textbox input

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I need to receive input from a textbox to update my xml file with new text.

I have this code script:

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string xmlPath = MapPath("xml/feed.xml");
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        //Check if the file already exists or not
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(xmlPath))
        {
            string Path2xml = MapPath("xml/feed.xml");
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(Path2xml);

            string txt2Title = txtTitle.Text;
            //xdoc.Element("CGTemplateDATA").Element("title").SetValue(txt2Title);
            // or even better option
            xdoc.Descendants("title").FirstOrDefault().SetValue(txt2Title);

            xdoc.Save(Path2xml);

            lblResult.Text = "XML dokumentet er blevet opdateret";
        }
        else
        {            
            XmlNode declarationNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes");
            doc.AppendChild(declarationNode);
            XmlNode bookNode = CreateBookNode(doc);                        
            //Append the cgtemplatedata node to the document
            doc.AppendChild(bookNode);
            lblResult.Text = "XML dokumentet er hermed oprettet";
            doc.Save(xmlPath);
        }
    }

    XmlNode CreateBookNode(XmlDocument doc)
    {
        XmlNode bookNode = doc.CreateElement("CGTemplateDATA");
        //Add all the children of the book node            
        XmlNode titleNode = doc.CreateElement("title");
        titleNode.InnerText = txtTitle.Text;
        bookNode.AppendChild(titleNode);

        XmlNode textNode = doc.CreateElement("text");
        textNode.InnerText = txtText.Text;
        bookNode.AppendChild(textNode);

        XmlNode referenceNode = doc.CreateElement("reference");
        referenceNode.InnerText = txtReference.Text;
        bookNode.AppendChild(referenceNode);

        return bookNode;
    }
</script>
```

It does not do anything with the text in title, and not as I exspect with the text from my textbox:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CGTemplateDATA>
  <title>Title</title>
  <text>put text here</text>
  <reference>put ref here</reference>
</CGTemplateDATA>
```

No errors shown, but it does'nt update with my string?

This is my webfom:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Storke-TV tekst</title>
    <link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <img alt="" class="style5" src="images/storke_tekst_top.png" /><br />
    <br />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="width: 586px">
                    <b>FORSIGTIG! Denne side giver direkte adgang til at opdatere storke tekst.</b><br />
                    <br />
                    1: Udfyld felterne.<br />
                    2: Tryk på GEM TEKST.<br />
                    3: Hvis du vil opdatere teksten, så ret den, og tryk på GEM TEKST igen.<br />
                </td>                               
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="width: 586px">&nbsp;</td>                               
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 85px; height: 40px">
                    Overskrift:
                </td>
                <td style="width: 501px; height: 40px">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" Width="182px" Height="28px" Text="string"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 85px; height: 41px">
                    Tekst:
                </td>
                <td style="width: 501px; height: 152px">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtText" Textmode="Multiline" runat="server" Width="240px" height="150"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 85px; height: 41px">
                    Henvisning:
                </td>
                <td style="width: 501px; height: 54px">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtReference" Textmode="Multiline" runat="server" Width="240px" Height="42px"></asp:TextBox>
                    &nbsp;<&nbsp;<asp:Button Text="Indsæt web henvisning" runat="server" ID="btnReftxt" Width="142px" Height="24" font-size="12px" OnClick="Save"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 85px; height: 41px">
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td style="width: 586px; height: 52px">
                    <asp:Button Text="GEM TEKST" runat="server" ID="btnSave" Width="240px" Height="40" OnClick="btnSave_Click"/>
                </td>                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 85px; height: 41px">
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td style="width: 586px; height: 41px">
                    <asp:Label Text="Gem tekst" runat="server" ID="lblResult" Width="295px"/>
                </td>                
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I can not figure it ou, but might be the answer is right in front of me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following.

**Step #1**

Add ***text*** attribute to the `asp:TextBox` as follows:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" Width="182px" Height="28px" Text="some InitialValue"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Step #2**

After that it will work when you are getting the textbox value

```
string txt2Title = txtTitle.Text;
```

For the reference, official Microsoft documentation: [TextBox Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Does not make any change, still not working.

Comment: Please edit your question, and add their the entire web form.

Comment: I've done that now

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/creating-a-basic-web-forms-page

Comment: https://asp.net-tutorials.com/basics/events/

Comment: But what do I miss?

Comment: I really don't know. Unfortunately, I don't have your environment to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I can change the title with either a text or with System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox but it will not use the text inside the textbox input. Do I miss something?